# How to make Array List Button with ViewPager with OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android

How to make Arraylist ViewPager in OnClick Listener?, I have 4 Activity MainTugas_1, MainTugas_2, MainTugas_3, MainTugas_4.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainTugas_2.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, title+ "\n"+description+"\n"+date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZuwh.png)

**MainKuliah.java**

```
    private void loadCards() {
    //init list
    modelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    //add items to list
    modelArrayList.add(new KModel(
            "Tugas 1 - Instalasi Android Studio",
            "Android Studio adalah lingkungan pengembangan terintegrasi resmi untuk sistem operasi Android Google, yang dibangun di perangkat lunak IntelliJ IDEA JetBrains dan dirancang khusus untuk pengembangan Android.",
            "10/10/2020",
            R.drawable.brochure));
    modelArrayList.add(new KModel(
            "BAB 2 - Intent",
            "Intent adalah mekanisme untuk melakukan sebuah aksi dan komunikasi antar komponen aplikasi pada platform Android. Atau dapat juga dijelaskan sebagai sebuah object yang memungkinkan kita untuk dapat berkomunikasi antara Activity satu dengan Activity lainnya.",
            "18/10/2020",
            R.drawable.namecard));
    modelArrayList.add(new KModel(
            "Tugas 3",
            "Description 03",
            "17/10/2020",
            R.drawable.poster));
    modelArrayList.add(new KModel(
            "Tugas 4",
            "Description 04",
            "17/10/2020",
            R.drawable.sticker));

    //setup adapter
    pAdapter = new PAdapter(this, modelArrayList);
    //set adapter to view pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(pAdapter);
    //set default padding
    viewPager.setPadding(100,0,100,0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved

```
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Class c=null;
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    c=MainTugas_2.class;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    c=MainPraktikum.class;
                    break;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, c);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(context, title+ "\n"+description+"\n"+date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```